# How to make span width to be maximum using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following example: ([live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gXDjZ/2/))

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>
        <strong>Stack</strong>
        <span>Overflow</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    background-color: #aaa;
}
span {
    background-color: #777;
}
```

How could I make `<span>`'s width to be all the available space?

**Note:** `<strong>` and `<span>` should be on the same line.

Comment: span {paddin-right:435px;} is this what you want ?

Comment: I don't want to fix the width!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the items on the same line with the full width taken up you could do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/Gfyjc/

```
p {
    background-color: #aaa;
}

strong {
    float: left;    
}

span {
    display: block;
    background-color: #777;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

But a better alternative would be to get the background-color run from the parent element.

Comment: And you don't even need `display:block` for the `strong` if you float it.

Comment: Looks good, thanks! BTW, the background colors are just to emphasize the widths.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gXDjZ/15/  to this you can add width:__px; to span to control its width

Comment: @MrLister - good point - I have removed it from the example and from the JS Fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the span to actually *be* that wide, only have it *look* like it is, you can simply give the `<p>` the background colour of the `<span`> in your example, and the `<strong>` the background colour of the `<p>`.

```
p {
    background-color: #777;
}
p strong {
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/tpFax/).

This only works correctly as long as the `<p>` has a padding of zero, though. Otherwise, you'll need the solution with the float.

Comment: +1 - you beat me to it, this was my suggestion for a better alternative to getting the background-color run if that is what the OP needs.

Comment: Well, it only works correctly if the `p` has no padding. Sorry about that. You know what, I'll put that in my answer.

Comment: That's not what I mean! The question states explicitly that `<span>`'s width should be adjusted here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block` to have possibility to set size and keep element positioned as inline elements. **Mathias** example changed to use `inline-block`: http://jsfiddle.net/gXDjZ/7/

Comment: This will require extra work to ensure IE7 and lower behave correctly.

Comment: if anyone still needs to bother with ie7 and lower ^^

Answer (score 1):

span is basically an inline element
making it a block element using display:block; will add a \n before n after the element

so making it a block will take the span to the next line and you can float:left; on its sibling and bring it back to the same line

something like this

```
strong{
  background-color: #aaa;
  float:left;  
}
span {
  display: block;
  background-color: #777;
}
```

you can also use padding-right:__px; in span
so that it takes up the adjacent spaces

```
 span{ padding-right:433px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gXDjZ/15/

Comment: Where do you get the value `433px` from?

Comment: it'll work only on jsfiddle with that width and nowhere else!!